# How can I caputre the email address from the cookie , when a user visits my website

Tags: email

SO I have got a website where visitors just come and see and then they leave, i could monetise on selling only if i would be able to capture there email address, I read couple of sites doing that ie when you visit there site and do not register or give the email address , they still capture it, How do they do that? Any inputs would be highly appreciated

Comment: Here we try and improve information security, not make it worse.

Comment: Welcome! You're question needs far more detail regarding what you've tried and how your web application works. Otherwise one can only speculate which doesn't tend to produce high quality answers.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't capture email address from the cookies. Not unless there is a previous known javascript trick the user enter the email and store it inside the cookies for anyone to retrieve it. (And with a cross domain cookies access rights ) .

HOWEVER, there is another way to steal email exploiting Browser Auto-complete/Auto-fill, by embedding hidden input filed into HTML form.  You can check out this web article for details: [Prevent Autofill From Stealing Your Personal Data](https://www.securecast.com/browser-autofill-vulnerability-test/).

Most Browsers already fix this blind autofill features, Chrome required a mouse click intervention to trigger the auto-fill. Nevertheless, one should not take the patch for granted. So it is a good idea to disable auto-fill or remove crucial personal info in auto-fills.